# Nesting Values with Java 8 stream and collector

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I have following data set to represent sales record:

```
 sn|    Channel    | Category   | Brand             |qty    |  gross |          
 1 |"Mini Market" | "Large MM" | "ARIEL"            |3      | 100 |
 2 |"Mini Market" | "Large MM" | "ARIEL"            |6      | 200| 
 3 |"Mini Market" | "Large MM" | "GILLETTE"         |12     | 103.88| 
 4 |"Mini Market" | "Large MM" | "OLAY"             |2      | 50  | 
 5 |"Mini Market" | "Large MM" | "OLAY"             |6      | 10| 
 6 |"Mini Market" | "Small MM" | "GILLETTE"         |5      | 20 |
 7 |"Mini Market" | "Small MM" | "GILLETTE"         |3      | 30| 
 8 |"Mini Market" | "Small MM" | "OLAY"             |3      | 80.3  |
 9 |"Mini Market" | "Small MM" | "ORAL B"           |6      | 100 |
 10|"Mini Market" | "Small MM" | "ORAL B"           |7      | 150 |
```

POJO Classes:

```
class SalesRecord{
    private String channel;
    private String category;
    private String brand;
    private int qty;
    private double gross;

    //getters and setters


}

class PivotTable {
    Map<Integer,Set<String>> uniqueAttirbuteMap;
    List<Pivot> pivot;
    //other fields and methods

}

class Pivot {
    public String attribute;
    Map<String, Double> aggregates;
    List<Pivot> pivotList;
    //other fields and methods

}
```

Custom Collector class:

```
public class SalesCollector implements Collector<SalesRecord,
    SalesCollector.Accumulator, PivotTable> {
    private static final String GROSS_SUM = "sum_gross";
    private static final String QTY_SUM = "sum_qty"

    public List<Double> prices = Lists.newArrayList();
    public List<Double> qtys = Lists.newArrayList();

    public double totalSales = 0;
    public double totalQty = 0;

     public SalesCollector(final List<GroupBy> groups) {
        this.groups = groups;
    }


    @Override
    public Supplier<Accumulator> supplier() {
        return () -> new Accumulator(this.groups, this);
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<Accumulator, SalesRecord> accumulator() {
        return Accumulator::accumulate;
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<Accumulator> combiner() {
        return Accumulator::combine;
    }

    @Override
    public Function<Accumulator, PivotTable> finisher() {
        return Accumulator::toSummary;
    }

    static class Accumulator {

        private final List<GroupBy> groups;
        private final SalesCollector collector;
        PivotTable pivotTable = new PivotTable();

        Accumulator(final List<GroupBy> groups, final SalesCollector collector) {
            this.groups = groups;
            this.collector = collector;
        }

         void accumulate(SalesRecord elem) {
          double sum = pivotTable.getAggregates().getOrDefault(GROSS_SUM, 0D) + elem.getGross();
            pivotTable.getAggregates().put(GROSS_SUM, sum);

             double qtySum = pivotTable.getAggregates().getOrDefault(QTY_SUM, 0D) + elem.getQty();
            pivotTable.getAggregates().put(QTY_SUM, qtySum);
        }

         Accumulator combine(Accumulator other) {

            final PivotTable summary = other.toSummary();

            double sum_qty =
                pivotTable.getAggregates().get(QTY_SUM) + summary.getAggregates().get(QTY_SUM);
            pivotTable.getAggregates().put(QTY_SUM, sum_qty);

            double sum_gross =
                pivotTable.getAggregates().get(GROSS_SUM) + summary.getAggregates().get(GROSS_SUM);
            pivotTable.getAggregates().put(GROSS_SUM, sum_gross);

            return this;
            }

            PivotTable toSummary() {
            double sumGross = pivotTable.getAggregates().get(GROSS_SUM);
            collector.prices.add(sumGross);
            collector.totalSales += sumGross;


            double sumQty = pivotTable.getAggregates().get(QTY_SUM);
            collector.qtys.add(sumQty);
            collector.totalQty += sumQty;

            return pivotTable;
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I am using stream and gropuing and have a custom collector to calculate values for qty and gross as follows:

```
SalesCollector collector = new SalesCollector(groups);
        final Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, PivotTable>>> results = salesRecords.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(SalesRecord::getChannel(), TreeMap::new,
                groupingBy(SalesRecord::getCategoryName(), TreeMap::new,
                    groupingBy(SalesRecord::getBrand(), TreeMap::new, collector))));

List<PivotTable> myList = results.values().stream()
            .map(Map::values)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(Map::values)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

My current result is as follows:

```
PivotTable(pivot:[Pivot(attribute:Mini Market), Pivot(attribute:Large MM), Pivot(attribute:ARIEL, aggregates:{ sum_qty=9, sum_gross=300 })])
PivotTable(pivot:[Pivot(attribute:Mini Market), Pivot(attribute:Large MM), Pivot(attribute:GILLETTE, aggregates:{ sum_qty = 12, sum_gross= 103.88})])
PivotTable(pivot:[Pivot(attribute:Mini Market), Pivot(attribute:Large MM), Pivot(attribute:OLAY, aggregates:{ sum_qty = 8, sum_gross= 60})])
PivotTable(pivot:[Pivot(attribute:Mini Market), Pivot(attribute:Small MM), Pivot(attribute:OLAY, aggregates:{ sum_qty = 3, sum_gross= 80.3})])
PivotTable(pivot:[Pivot(attribute:Mini Market), Pivot(attribute:Small MM), Pivot(attribute:GILLETTE, aggregates:{ sum_qty = 8, sum_gross= 50})])
PivotTable(pivot:[Pivot(attribute:Mini Market), Pivot(attribute:Small MM), Pivot(attribute:ORAL B, aggregates:{ sum_qty = 13, sum_gross= 250})])
```

What I'm trying to achieve is as follows:

```
PivotTable(pivot:[Pivot(attribute:Mini Market), Pivot(attribute:Large MM), pivotList:[Pivot(attribute:ARIEL, aggregates:{ sum_qty=9, sum_gross=300 }),
Pivot(attribute:GILLETTE, aggregates:{ sum_qty = 12, sum_gross= 103.88}),Pivot(attribute:OLAY, aggregates:{ sum_qty = 8, sum_gross= 60})])
PivotTable(pivot:[Pivot(attribute:Mini Market), Pivot(attribute:Small MM), Pivot(attribute:GILLETTE, aggregates:{ sum_qty = 8, sum_gross= 50})]),
Pivot(attribute:OLAY, aggregates:{ sum_qty = 3, sum_gross= 80.3}),Pivot(attribute:ORAL B, aggregates:{ sum_qty = 13, sum_gross= 250})])
```

To put it simply, I want nesting as follows:

```
Mini Market:
    Large MM:
        ARIEL: {sum_qty = 9, sum_gross= 300}
        GILLETTE: {sum_qty = 12, sum_gross= 103.88}
        OLAY: {sum_qty = 8, sum_gross= 60}

Mini Market:
    Small MM:
        GILLETTE: {sum_qty = 8, sum_gross= 50}
        OLAY: {sum_qty = 3, sum_gross= 80.3}
        ORAL B: {sum_qty = 13, sum_gross= 250}
```

Is it possible to achive this with current collector result itself with same grouping? What would be best way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you share the `PivotTable` and `SalesRecord` POJOs? Also, what is the data type of the result that you are expecting now?

Comment: @nullpointer I've added the POJOs. The data type of the result expected id list<PivotTable>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I extended your stream by the missing `collector`. It's a dedicated `Collector` which maps each `SalesRecord` to a `Map<String, Double>`. Since `Map` has one value type I decided to use `Double`.

```
    Supplier<Map<String, Double>> supplier = TreeMap::new;
    BiConsumer<Map<String, Double>, SalesRecord> biConsumer = (map, sr) -> {
        map.merge("sum_qty", Double.valueOf(sr.getQty()), (qtySum, qty) -> qtySum + qty);
        map.merge("sum_gross", sr.getGross(), (grossSum, gross) -> grossSum + gross);
    };
    BinaryOperator<Map<String, Double>> binaryOperator = (l, r) -> {
        l.compute("sum_qty", (k, v) -> v + r.get("sum_qty"));
        l.compute("sum_gross", (k, v) -> v + r.get("sum_gross"));
        return l;
    };
    Collector<SalesRecord, Map<String, Double>, Map<String, Double>> collector = Collector.of(supplier, biConsumer, binaryOperator);
```

Now addded as the last downstream collector to the stream:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Double>>>> grouped = salesRecords.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        SalesRecord::getChannel, TreeMap::new,
        Collectors.groupingBy(SalesRecord::getCategory, TreeMap::new,
                Collectors.groupingBy(SalesRecord::getBrand, collector))));
```

The result is a `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Double>>>> grouped` and looks like that (added line breaks for readability):

```
{Mini Market=   
               {Large MM={
                            OLAY={sum_gross=60.0, sum_qty=8.0}, 
                            ARIEL={sum_gross=300.0, sum_qty=9.0},
                            GILLETTE={sum_gross=103.88, sum_qty=12.0}},
                Small MM={
                            OLAY={sum_gross=80.3, sum_qty=3.0},
                            ORAL B={sum_gross=250.0, sum_qty=13.0},
                            GILLETTE={sum_gross=50.0, sum_qty=8.0}}
                }
}
```

Comment: As far as I see `SalesCollector` / `Accumulator` build the sums. Why did you seaprate the code between `SalesCollector` and `Accumulator`? They are [tightly coupled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling).

Comment: You asked is it "possible to achive this with current collector result itself with same grouping?" I did it. And: "What would be best way to achieve this?" I don't want to say, my answer shows the _best way_ but I think the code shown has less overhead than `SalesCollector` / `Accumulator`.

Comment: So my question now is how do I get the output as List<Pivot> instead and not Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Double>>>> where 'attribute' of Pivot being value of channel/category/brand and aggregates being sum values?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. The variable `grouped` corresponds to the field `aggregates` of `Pivot`. But I don't know what the purpose of `Pivot.attribute` is.

Comment: It's because the grouping can be in multiple levels not just three as in question. If I were to return result simply as Map then I would require to set the result  to multiple Map variables based on level of grouping. For example for 2 lvl grouping Map<String,Map<String,Double>> for 3 would be Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Double>>>>. Instead what I'm trying to achieve is to return result as list<Object> regardless of level of grouping.

Comment: Even based on your last comment I still don't understand, what your goal is. The comments section here is limited. I suggest you, to ask a new question based on this question and how far you now got. But If you do, try to show some cases. For example based on what input there should be "2 lvl grouping" and which content should the resulting map have. The better you explain what you want to achieve the more likely someone comes up with a good answer.